# Clipping polylines with polygon boundary in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, clip

I want to clip the lines with polygon and also I want to export it as separate shapefile. Can we able to do this task in MapInfo Pro 15.2 without using MapInfo Discover?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with MapInfo Pro.

1. Make the line layer editable
2. Select the lines to cut
3. Set these as Target using SPATIAL, Edit, Set Target (or Ctrl + T)
4. Select the cutting polygon
5. Use SPATIAL, Edit, Split, Split Target to split the lines with the polygon
6. Save the changes to your table

To save the result into Shape, use Universal Translator. If it has been loaded you will find it here TABLE, Content, Universal Translator.

If you can't see, go to HOME, Tools and run the tool from the Registered tab.